# how to put logout action(not page) to a logout link in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, menu, logout

I have a menu where when users are logged in, one of the menu items is "logout".  Currently I send them to a logout page where they click a link to logout, but can i log them out when clicking the "logout" menu link?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the below mentioned link to make user logout :

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">Logout</a>
```

It will logout the user and redirect him to homepage.

For detailed information, checkout here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url

EDIT:

You can achieve this using the `wp_nav_menu_items` hook. Let's have a look at the following piece of code which shows the login/logout link on the `primary` menu location.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wti_loginout_menu_link', 10, 2 );

function wti_loginout_menu_link( $items, $args ) {
   if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {
      if (is_user_logged_in()) {
         $items .= '<li class="right"><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Log Out</a></li>';
      } else {
         $items .= '<li class="right"><a href="'. wp_login_url(get_permalink()) .'">Log In</a></li>';
      }
   }
   return $items;
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: ok but where do i put in the wp admin?  basically w/o getting into the php files how can i do the above thru admin?

Comment: Please check the updated answer, it will add the login/logout menu item with your menu items and then you will not need to add the link from admin.

Comment: like i said, how can i do this w/o any php?  Any way to do it through admin?